# BottomNavigationView inside AppBarLaout

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to place the BottomNavigationView on the tool bar with scrolling behaviour similar to Facebook

[image: Facebook].

I was able to place the BottomNavigationView on the top and achieve the desired behaviour. However, the BottomNavigationView have an elevation that I can't eliminate.

[image: Result]

Here is the layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_new_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/searchable_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_bottom_nav_menu"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:background="@color/activity_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
             android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:text="@string/title_home" />

    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Does anyone knows where the problem is? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove **elevation** on **BottomNavigationView** then add this **app:elevation="0dp"**

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @Mohit Suthar, but I tried before writing the post, and didn't work.

Comment: add this also app:elevation="0dp" in toolbar, showing toolbar shadow may be possible

Comment: Thanks again. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

try this use `app:elevation="0dp"` property of your `BottomNavigationView` to to remove  elevation `BottomNavigationView`  like below sample code

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/navigation"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
      app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
      app:elevation="0dp"
      app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
      app:menu="@menu/activity_main_bottom_nav_menu"/>
```

Comment: Ok, I know where was the problem. I put android:elevation="0dp" instead of app:elevation="0dp". Thanks @Nilesh. I wont check the answer as correct because Mohit Suthar was first. Sorry about it, but I really appreciate it.

Comment: @user274051 no worries happy to help you